# How to confgure capslock as a standalone key?

Tags: keys, autokey

In Windows, you can use AutoHotKey to make Capslock a standalone key (say, binding it to 'escape') as well as a modifier (so that you can bind, say 'CapsLock + k', to launch a browser).

I've tried everything under sun to make CapsLock have its own special binding PLUS make it a modifier key in Ubuntu and Xubuntu, and tried various Autokey python scripts, but it seems this is not possible on Ubuntu/Xubuntu?

Am I wrong? Does anyone know a way this could be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found my solution with the [Xcape](https://github.com/alols/xcape) which allows you to send key events when modifier keys are released on his own.

Comment: Did you get capslock to act as its own modifier key instead of just being a duplicate ctrl / shift / esc, etc.? If so, how?

Comment: Yes: http://tiborsimko.org/capslock-escape-control.html

Answer (score 4):

Try this in a console:

```
setxkbmap -option caps:none
xmodmap -e 'keycode 66 = Multi_key';
```

Than your <kbd>Caps-Lock</kbd> work as a <kbd>Compose</kbd> key.

Ie: If you hit successively:

- <kbd>Compose</kbd>, <kbd>o</kbd>, then <kbd>e</kbd> will render "œ",
- <kbd>Compose</kbd>, <kbd>o</kbd>, then <kbd>r</kbd> will render "®",
- <kbd>Compose</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd>, then <kbd>4</kbd> will render "¾",
- <kbd>Compose</kbd>, <kbd>o</kbd>, then <kbd>/</kbd> will render "ø",
- <kbd>Compose</kbd>, <kbd>+</kbd>, then <kbd>-</kbd> will render "±",
- <kbd>Compose</kbd>, <kbd>s</kbd>, then <kbd>s</kbd> will render "ß",
- ...

And so on.

Comment: Thanks F. Hauri, but I was specifically looking for a method where the capslock works as modifier keys when combining with another key. If not combining and released on his own, it will send a key event then. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If you install [gnome tweak-tool](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-tweak-tool/), you can redefine `Caps-Lock` from the `Typing` tab.

You can make it for instance an `Escape` or `Ctrl`. I've turned it into a `BackSpace`.

You can install it using:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.